# How to check if user is following on twitter without any authentication

Tags: php, twitter

Actually I have two questions :)

1. I want to check if @usernameA is following to @usernameB without any authentication. I know it is possible. (See this : http://www.followercheck.com/.) But I don't know how is it possible? Is there any public api (that may i don't know) ? Please help me.
2. How can I get username who is logged in twitter whithout any authentication (Without Twitter Application authentication) (Any alternative solution will helip me)

I can solve both problem using twitter API 1.1 (By authentication) But I don't want to use it because It has limitation. One can make 15 call per 15 minute (From single IP).

Thanks in advance.